# Best way to resize/size arrays while the program is running

Tags: c

I am trying to take in array which contains some integer values/string values from the user, and not sure how long the array is going to be.. If i intitalise like array[500], i know it is a poor solution and poor programming skills.. How do i improve this?

Sample code below:

```
int main(void){
    int t=0;
    char str[200];
    int  count[20];
    printf("Please enter the number of test cases(between 1 to 20):");
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for ( int i = 1; i<=t;i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter each of %i test case values:",i);
        gets(str);
        //set_create(str);
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<t;i++)
    {
        prinf("%i",count[i]);
        printf("\n");
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

The code above is wrong definitely.. Need some help to improve the code...Thanks

Edited code:

```
 int main(void){
        int T=0;
        int *count; 
        printf("Please enter the number of test cases(between 1 to 20):");
        scanf("%d",&T);
        count = malloc(T * sizeof *count);
        for ( int i = 1; i<=T;i++)
        {
            printf("Please enter each of %i test case values:",i);
            fgets(count);
            printf("\n");
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a pointer and malloc / realloc memory as needed. Don't use `gets` - it's unsafe and no longer in the standard. Use `fgets` instead.

For example, if you don't know how many `count` elements you need:

```
int *count;

scanf("%d", &t);
count = malloc(t * sizeof *count);
```

Comment: is it good to use new and delete to dynamically allocate arrays?

Comment: @lakesh Only if you use C++ :-) You tagged the question `c` and your code looks really c-ish.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I have edited the answer to the question above. Is it better now? any corrections?

Comment: @lakesh You're using `fgets` on an `int *`. That makes *no sense*. You need to follow a C book.

Answer (score 1):

In such situation you can allocate memory for array in heap with functions `malloc/calloc` or on the stack with function `alloca()` (in header `"alloca.h"`);